# Неверно обрабатывается UTF-8 в response()->setStatusCode() в Laravel

Tags: php, javascript, json, laravel, http

Есть некая форма, с которой отправляются некие данные, отправляются через функцию `$.ajax()`:

```
f.on('submit', function (e) {
        var d = f.serialize();
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: u,
            type: 'POST',
            data: d,
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: b,
            error: function (jqXHR) {
                //
            },
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                // внимание сюда, отдельно радует наличие textStatus и jqXHR.statusText
                alert(jqXHR.statusText);
            }
        });
    });
```

На мой взгляд, более верно передавать сообщения о статусе ответов в специально расположенном для этого месте, в `jqXHR.statusText`, а `data` оставлять либо пустым, либо наполнять реальными данными.

В этом случае у нас не будет путаницы с содержанием ответов, когда там бывает то `json`, то `text`, который возможно стоит не выводить обычным текстом, а оборачивать в бессмысленный `json`, ради унификации кода.

Это может быть важным, когда мы используем стандартные функции по обработке `submit` форм, когда все типы получаемых и отправляемых данных желательно привести к единому виду. Соответственно, в контроллере мы (пытаемся) делаем нечто такое:

```
public function contactUs(ContactUsRequest $request)
    {
        // что-нибудь

        return response(json_encode([... массив / пустота ...]))
            ->header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            ->header('charset', 'utf-8')
            ->setStatusCode(201, 'Сообщение успешно отправлено.')
            ;
    }
```

Проблема в том, что при установке кодировки подобным образом это влияет только лишь на выводимые `массив / пустота` (я проверял), а вот на `statusText` - нет, не влияет, получим привычную абракадабру, которая обычно получается при неверной обработке `utf-8`.

Так вот, вопрос: в чем может быть проблема? У меня лично три варианта:

1. Баг Laravel.
2. Ограничение стандарта по выводу сообщений о статусе http-ответов.
3. Я что-то упускаю и делаю не так.

*Зачем мне такой код? В целом незачем, просто изучаю тонкости.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже сам нашел ответ на свой вопрос [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36473475/is-it-possible-to-set-custom-status-message-in-utf-8-in-http-status-header). Причин не делать так, как я описал, то есть не использовать utf-8 в статусе ответа от сервера, две:

1. Кодировка данного текста не определена, а значит использовать не ASCII символы бесполезно.
2. В стандарте HTTP/2 этот текст в принципе не используется, так что рано или поздно от него придется отказаться.